# Is it possible to trace postal code and area code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trace postal code and area code by a code written in PHP? 
I can trace IP, country, state, city etc. But can I use that information to trace postal code or area code and if not, how is it possible to trace it? I can't use online websites etc. for tracing a single postal code or area code, because it is for a website itself.

I have searched the internet, but the only thing I find are websites that provide this service, and no code that I can use.

At the end I need to trace:
Postal code in the US and Canada
Area code in the US and Canada

Comment: can't you contact a webservice with your php code? Can't you contact a webservice via ajax?

Comment: How can I do that? For example here it traces what I need, but how can I extract the values and use it in my code? http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js

Comment: What do you mean by "trace postal code and area code"? Are you trying to determine the postal code that the request originated from (i.e. where the user is located) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you can trace country, state, city, what about creating a dictionary(DB-Table) so you can match these parameters and get the right postal code yourself. Other homepages probably do exactly the same.

Create something like that: http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/

Comment: It is not accurate, because for example Alabama has zip codes from 35801 thru 35816. So I can't use it for what I need

Comment: Updated the link with a better list and I hope you get the principal idea of what I want to tell you.

Comment: I know what you are trying to explain, but using this method is inaccurate. Because one city or state can have different postal codes. Is there any other way?

Comment: What about this php function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.geoip-record-by-name.php

Comment: How can I use it? I am running windows and the server with PHP is online. So I can't use linux commands. Do you have a page where it explains how to install geoiplite?

Comment: May you use one of these .dll files: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/geoip/1.0.8/
If you don't know how to install it may have a look here:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Comment: Ok here is my problem, What if I can't install anything on the PHP because it is located on a server? In this case 000webhost.com. And why do I need to install anything? Can't I just drag and drop the files into the server and use them?

Comment: Well ok that's a problem because then I think you don't have access to php.ini and/or the php\extensions directory.
I think then you can only use one of [MaxMinds APIs](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/) or something similar. Problem with that: you may have to pay for this service.

Comment: Ok thanks anyways for your help, I will try something else